# What is the easiest way to configure NServiceBus to allow NodaTime entities in XML-serialized messages?

Tags: xml, nservicebus, nodatime

I would like to be able to use NodaTime entities in some NServiceBus messages, however, the built-in xml serialization does not support them.  Is there are straight-forward way to add my own serializers for specific types as part of the endpoint configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NServiceBus does not currently support that.
You would have to replace the whole serializer.

Comment: Do you know if the JSON serializer would support them?

Comment: @UdiDahan - Yes, they work with the JSON serializer using the NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet additions.

Comment: Then, unless there is some strict reason for staying the XML serializer, just tell NServiceBus to use JSON serialization.